# Merging features (lines) in shapefile with same name using Python and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I am working with the NHD flowline dataset (USGS) and some of the line features have the same name. I want to merge the line features that have the same name. For example: There are three features that have the name "Kings River" and four features that have the name "Boulder Creek" how do I write a python script that merges these features based on the name? The question [How to merge multiple overlapping lines using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138667/how-to-merge-multiple-overlapping-lines-using-python) deals with a merge that is based on geometry - I need to merge the line features based on a non spatial attribute (name of flowline).

Comment: Is this the [earlier Q&A](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/how-can-i-merge-lines-with-same-name-and-intersect-each-other) that you are referring to, or was it another?  Either way, whenever referencing earlier Q&As all you have to do is to copy/paste their URLs into your question and they act as magic links to automatically display their titles.  Would you be able to use the [edit] button to clarify which Q&A you are referencing, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple overlapping lines using python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138667/how-to-merge-multiple-overlapping-lines-using-python)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138667/how-to-merge-multiple-overlapping-lines-using-python is not the same thing. The merge is not based on geometry - it's based on a non spatial attribute

Comment: @user1987819872313 if you think it is not a duplicate then I recommend editing that into the beginning of your question and say precisely why not.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/how-can-i-merge-lines-with-same-name-and-intersect-each-other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the two following functions:

1. **Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Shapefiles to One...** in order to make one shapefile from the different ones you have (it seems that they are all line geometries so this will work).
2. **Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve** in order to merge the features based on the name attribute (this function asks for a merge attribute).

I have not tried this on a sample but it should work. 'hope I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @wiltomap (and basically building on what he said), the **Dissolve** function sounds like it should do what you're asking for - merging multiple features by their common attribute name. If you want it using **Python**, you could use the following:

```
import processing

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
field = 'FieldName'
output = "C:\Users\you\Desktop\\result.shp"
processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", layer, 'False', field, output)
```

Hope this helps!